# Android id is change the same app is run on two different Monitor and apk build how to solve? please tell me the answer

Tags: android

```
public static String getHardwareId(Context context) {
        return Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    }



build.gradle

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fieldforce"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 8
        versionName "V8.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
```

Comment: `ANDROID_ID` is documented here: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/Settings.Secure#android_id What is your question?

Comment: android id is change the app is app is unistalled and again istalled.

Comment: What do you mean by "two different monitor"?

Comment: means two different PC the android studio installed and same code run on it that condition the android id get different

Answer (score 2):

> Values of `ANDROID_ID` are **scoped by signing key** and user.

Source: [Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/Settings.Secure#android_id), emphasis mine.

When you first start Android development on a computer a debug signing key is generated for you in `~/.android/debug.keystore`. It's different for every development machine. This key is used to sign debug builds of all your apps on this machine.

This means that `ANDROID_ID` will be different for the same app signed with different debug keys. It also means you can't update an app built on one PC with an app built on another PC without uninstalling the app first. (Remember this for later!)

#### Project dev key

What I do is copy one of those keys into my project so that the key is used by all developers for this specific project.

Step 1: Copy one of these `debug.keystore` files to your project root.

[image: Copy debug.keystore]

Step 2: Modify your *app* build.gradle like so:

```
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile = rootProject.file("debug.keystore")
    }
}
```

Step 3: Make sure all developers use the updated project.

Comment: what u mean by debug.keystore

Comment: Every app has to be signed before it can be installed. Even debug build. For debug build the signature is in `~/.android/debug.keystore` (Linux) or `C:\Users\<your-user-name>\.android\debug.keystore` (Windows). Every developer on every PC has their own generated `debug.keystore`. Pick one of these files, copy it to your project and make your project use this file for debug builds. So it's independent of developer machine.

Comment: signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("C://Users//User//.android//debug.keystore")
        }
    }                         "It is Correct or not"

Comment: No. That's the default. You don't want that. *Copy the file to your project directory.*

Comment: how to add debug.keystore file in android studio?

Comment: If the ANDROID_ID depends on the sign key used, then there's no way to use the ANDROID_ID as a unique ID to identify different devices. I believe it'd be the same ANDROID_ID if different devices are using the same sign key (as in release version uploaded to the play store). I haven't test this though.

Comment: @RamiroG.M. "combination of app-signing key, user, and device" Please see the Source link.